# PHP dice game with classes

Tags: php, class, oop

I'm trying to develop the 'roll the dice' with classes in PHP and with two dice and several players, do you know how the structure could be better? I've started with this simple code:

```
class dice extends nplayer{
private $face1;
private $face2;
public function roll(){
    $die = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6');
    $randDie = array_rand($die);
    $this->face1=$randDie;
...
}
}

class nplayer{
private $name;

private function __construct($nam){
    $this->namw=$nam;
}

public function play(){
    $this->roll();
}
public function show($name){
    print "<...>";
}
}
class resuts{
}
```

Comment: This looks like incomplete code and would not compile. This would get closed on Code Review unless/until the actual, complete working code is included.

Comment: @Phrancis since when is it a pre to include complete working code? Never heard of such a thing. The OP has started working on some code an his problem is that there isn't any question that resolves to a problem in the applied code, therefor it's not reproducible .. So flag it

Comment: @dbf seems like a good question for Stack Overflow if that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `roll()` can look like this:
`$this->face1 = rand(1,6);`
and that's it. You do not need array to dice some number.

You shouldn't call `$this->roll();` in class `nplayer` because this class do not have method `roll()`